# How do I built RESTful services with WCF?

Tags: wcf, rest

Forgive my ignorance but is it possible to build RESTful services with WCF or would I need some other technology entirely to do this.  I understand, roughly, what RESTful services are but was just wondering about how to built them in .NET.

Comment: Code Project has this article: [Create and Consume RESTFul Service in .NET Framework 4.0](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/255684/Create-and-Consume-RESTFul-Service-in-NET-Framewor) This should get you started...

Comment: you may also consider ASP.NET Web API